# How to fetch payment details using Razorpay

Tags: razorpay

I can able to fetch the payment ID using the razorpay API...But now I want to fetch other payment details rather than payment ID... How can I fetch the datails from Razorpay

Answer (score 0):

You can use this GET call to get all details once payment_id is known:

curl -u : \https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/**pay_29QQoUBi66xm2f**

Sample response will be:

{    "id": "**pay_29QQoUBi66xm2f**",    "entity": "payment",    "amount": 5000,    "currency": "INR",    "status": "captured",    "order_id": null,    "invoice_id": null,    "international": false,    "method": "wallet",    "amount_refunded": 0,    "refund_status": null,    "captured": true,    "description": "Purchase Description",    "card_id": null,    "bank": null,    "wallet": "freecharge",    "vpa": null,    "email": "a@b.com",    "contact": "91xxxxxxxx",    "notes": {        "merchant_order_id": "order id"    },    "fee": 1438,    "tax": 188,    "error_code": null,    "error_description": null,    "created_at": 1400826750}

Hope this helps :)

Comment: its asking email id password when hit API can you please tell me  what email and password we need to add